# Loop through number array to construct object of index nodes in plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array such as `[2,5,3,1]` each number represents an index number. How would I be able to construct an object path using these nodes? For example:

[2,5] would create:

```
myObject.conversations[i].conversations[i]
```

[2,5,3,1] would create:

```
myObject.conversations[i].conversations[i].conversations[i].conversations[i]
```

I can only use basic javascript - es6, es5 etc not allowed. I tried a for loop to construct a string which I could just keep adding to but it didn’t work.

Comment: basic is ecma. please add the language version and your try.

Comment: If you cannot use ecmascript, you cannot use Javascript...

Comment: Sorry I meant I can't use es6, es5 etc. I'll update answer.

Comment: If you can't use ES5 or ES6 you can't use Javascript :) These are JS versions (ES6 = JS 2015)

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward typeof myObject is ? Object or Array ?

Comment: ECMA *is* JavaScript, so if you can't use ECMA, this is equivalent to you saying you can't use any JavaScript code. Don't take my word for it, just look it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the indices array and use a variable for getting the nested references.

```
var temp = myObject, // start value
    indices = [2, 5, 3, 1],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    temp = temp.conversations[indices[i]];
}

// use temp
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the only problem I have is that with this ansert the 'myObject' would repeat everytime, and I can only have it at the start if that makes sense.

Comment: i don't get you. do you have an example?

Comment: It won't repeat, it will get to the child conversations array if the indexes are correct

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `.reduce`

```js
console.log(
    [2,5,3,1].reduce(function(carry, current) {
        return carry + '.conversations[' + current +']';
    }, 'myObject')
)
```

And if you want the actual object (not the string path), it's as simple as:

```
[2,5,3,1].reduce(function(carry, current) {
    return carry.conversations[current];
}, myObject)
```

Or if you want to only pass in `myObject` once:

```
function conversation(myObject) {
    return function(path) {
        return path.reduce(function(carry, current) {
            return carry.conversations[current];
        }, myObject)
    }
}
```

And then you just do

```
var convo = conversation(myObject);

convo([2, 3, 5, 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the only problem I have is that with this ansert the 'myObject' would repeat everytime, and I can only have it at the start if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that can help.

```
let obj = 'myObject';
[2,5,3,1].forEach(i => {
  obj += `.conversations[${i}]`;
});
eval(obj);
```